# Why can't I access $data on Vue 3 instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I've got a strange problem: I'm unable to access data() from a vue instance:

```
const vueapp = Vue.createApp({
  data(){
    return {
      form:{ .... }
[etc..]

// later:

console.log(vueapp.$data, vueapp.form) // both undefined
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance

The app and its root component are subtly but importantly different. The options you pass to `createApp` don't exist on the app, but its root component.

> The options passed to createApp are used to configure the root component. That component is used as the starting point for rendering when we mount the application.
>
> ```
> const app = Vue.createApp(RootComponent)
> const vm = app.mount('#app')
> ```

You can do `vm.$data` and `vm.form` in the above code sample, but not `app.$data` or `app.form`.

Comment: Thank you. And inside lifecycle hooks, I can just use this (in vue 3 it refers to the root component)